# JSON PHP ForEach

Tags: php, json, foreach

JSON FEED:

```
    {
        "Group": [
          {
             "name": "HolderOne",
            "operators": [
            {
                "username": "ken",
                "status": 3
            },
     .....etc.....
```

CODE:

```
 <?php 
 $json = file_get_content('path to feed');
 $data=json_decode($json); 

 echo $data->cGroup[0]->operators[0]->username; //WORKS!

 if (is_array($data->Group->operators))
  { foreach($data->Group->operators as $operator) 
     {if($operator->username == "ken") {echo $operator->status;}} 
  } else { echo 'NOT AN ARRAY'; } //DOESNT WORK - DISPLAYS NOT AN ARRAY
 ?>
```

I am trying to say if the username is Ken (or whatever I specify when I code more) display the correspoding status.

So...

```
  echo $data->Group[0]->operators[0]->username; //WORKS!
```

but...

```
    foreach($data->Group->operators as $operator) {if($operator->username == "ken") {echo $operator->status;}}
```

...doesn't - probably something obvious, but can anyone see my problem?

Cheers
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have to be `$data->Group[0]->operators`, or loop through the `Groups` and have another loop inside...

```
foreach($data->Group as $group){
    foreach($group->operators as $operator){
        if($operator->username == "ken") {echo $operator->status;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's true:

```
foreach($data["Group"]["operators"] as $operators)
{
     if($operators["username"] == "ken")
     {
          echo $operators["status"];
     }
     else
     {
          echo 'NOT AN ARRAY';
     }
}
```